# if parent div doesn't contain specific span element then hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of comments built like this :

```
<article class="comment">
<span class="field"></span>
</article>
```

Inside my page some `<article class="comment">` doesn't contain the 
`<span class="field"></span>` and I need to display just the ones which have that `span` element.

I've tried this:  `jQuery('article.comment:not(:has(span.field)').hide();`

Tried this also:

```
if (jQuery('span.field').length) {
jQuery('article.comment').show();
 } 
else { jQuery('article.comment').hide(); }
```

but this is hiding all the `article.comment` divs and I want to hide just the ones without the `span` element.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis, the one closing the `:not`:

```
jQuery('article.comment:not(:has(span.field))').hide();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qdCjP/

Comment: I like this better than my each loop!

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is more readable, but i think it is slower. Anyway, i'm just telling the OP why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
jQuery('article.comment').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).find('.field').length) {
        jQuery(this).show();
    } else {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the articles and hide or show each one based on the field existing -

```
 jQuery('article.comment').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).find('.field').length) {
        jQuery(this).show();
    } else {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse all spans and show their parents.

```
jQuery('article').hide();
jQuery('article span.field').each(function( i, elem){
    $(elem).parent().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
jQuery(".comment").hide();
jQuery(".comment .field").parent().show();
```